# Android listview and VirtulaKeyboard

Tags: android

i have listview and editText ,i need to scroll the last item of the listview to top of the soft keyboard ,how can i done this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add these property in the listview.

```
android:stackFromBottom="false"
android:transcriptMode="alwaysScroll"
```